# Can I use gradle to minify then combine source files like uglifyjs does?

Tags: javascript, gradle, minify

I am using the excellent eriwen gradle.js [plugin](https://github.com/eriwen/gradle-js-plugin) to combine and then minify my js.

In my *build.gradle* file I have

```
plugins {
      id "com.eriwen.gradle.css" version "1.11.1"
      id "com.eriwen.gradle.js" version "1.12.1"
}

// other stuff

def jsSrcDir = 'src/main/webapp/js'

combineJs {
    source = fileTree(jsSrcDir)
    dest = file('all.js')
}

minifyJs {
    source = combineJs
    dest = file('all-min.js')
    sourceMap = file('all.sourcemap.js')
    closure {
        warningLevel = 'QUIET'
        compilerOptions.languageIn = "ECMASCRIPT5"
    }
}
```

When I run `gradle minfyJs`, in my source map I have

```
"sources":["/home/userb/projects/alpha1/all.js"],
```

If I use uglifyjs (as described [here](http://sethlakowske.com/software/use-grunt-and-uglifyjs-to-combine-multiple-javascript-files-into-a-single-javascript-file/)), I wind up with

```
uglifyjs src/main/webapp/**/*.js --source-map sourceMap.json -o blah.js
```

sourceMap.json contains

```
"sources":["src/main/webapp/bootstrap3-js/bootstrap.js","src/main/webapp/bootstrap3-js/bootstrap.min.js","src/main/webapp/bootstrap3-js/jquery-2.1.1.js","src/main/webapp/bootstrap3-js/postrope-global.js","src/main/webapp/bootstrap3-js/snap.js","src/main/webapp/bootstrap3-js/snap.min.js","src/main/webapp/js/analytics.js","src/main/webapp/js/BlobBuilder.js","src/main/webapp/js/Blob.js","src/main/webapp/js/bootstrap2.2.1.js","src/main/webapp/js/bootstrap2.3.2.js","src/main/webapp/js/bootstrap.file-upload.js","src/main/webapp/js/bootstrap-modal-enhance.js","src/main/webapp/js/bootstrap-select.min.js","src/main/webapp/js/bootstrap-transition.js","src/main/webapp/js/canvas-toBlob.js","src/main/webapp/js/cbpSplitLayout.js","src/main/webapp/js/classie.js","src/main/webapp/js/countries.en.js","src/main/webapp/js/custom-animation.js","src/main/webapp/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js","src/main/webapp/js/jquery-1.9.1.js","src/main/webapp/js/jquery.autocomplete.js","src/main/webapp/js/jquery.blockUI.js","src/main/webapp/js/jQuery.circleMenu.js","src/main/webapp/js/jquery.clingify.min.js","src/main/webapp/js/jquery-color.js","src/main/webapp/js/jquery.confirm2.js","src/main/webapp/js/jquery.confirm.js","src/main/webapp/js/jquery.confirm.min.js","src/main/webapp/js/jquery.fileupload.js","src/main/webapp/js/jquery.flexslider.js","src/main/webapp/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js","src/main/webapp/js/jquery.masonry.min.js","src/main/webapp/js/jquery.timeago.js","src/main/webapp/js/jquery.ui.widget.min.js","src/main/webapp/js/jquery.unveil.js","src/main/webapp/js/jquery.waitforimages.js","src/main/webapp/js/jquery.wookmark.js","src/main/webapp/js/livestamp.min.js","src/main/webapp/js/location.js","src/main/webapp/js/main.js","src/main/webapp/js/modernizr-2.6.2.js","src/main/webapp/js/modernizr.custom2.js","src/main/webapp/js/modernizr.custom.js","src/main/webapp/js/moment.min.js","src/main/webapp/js/offer.js","src/main/webapp/js/parsley.js","src/main/webapp/js/ProgressButtons.js","src/main/webapp/js/raphael.js","src/main/webapp/js/register.js","src/main/webapp/js/rope_utility.js","src/main/webapp/js/signup_utility.js","src/main/webapp/js/static-jquery.js","src/main/webapp/js/static-jquery.mega.js","src/main/webapp/js/static-jquery-migrate.min.js","src/main/webapp/js/utility.js","src/main/webapp/js/waypoints.min.js"]
```

The result from uglify is what I want. It is keeping track of all the source files in my sourcemap so I can identify bugs in my JS quicker.
I would like to know if I can achieve a similar outcome with the gradle plugins? I dont want to run uglify from my gradle task - I would prefer to modify the gradle plugins to do what I want. Being lazy though I don't want to write any code if the gradle plugins already do this.

Can I achieve the uglifyJs outcome using gradle plugins?

Comment: So as far as I understood you're looking for a plugin? If so, this question is to be closed as it violates the SO rules.

Comment: No I'm not looking for a plugin. I have found the plugin (as mentioned in the question) and am looking for advice on whether I need to extend the plugin to achieve my programming task.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, the documentation of that plugin is not very good. 
Just don't use combineJs, minifyJs is capable of combining sources too:

```
minifyJs {
    source = fileTree(jsSrcDir)
    dest = file('all-min.js')
    sourceMap = file('all.sourcemap.js')
    closure {
        warningLevel = 'QUIET'
        compilerOptions.languageIn = "ECMASCRIPT5"
    }
}
```